# Change view on specific key pressed in MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am building a little application using WPF and the MVVM pattern. In particular, I want to display structured data in a TreeView. To keep things simple, let's assume that I have created an Interface IParentVM which defines an

```
ObservableCollection<IParent> ListOfChildren { get; }
```

as an ItemsSource and implement this Interface in several classes, say ClassA and ClassB. These classes have a lot more properties, two common properties are

```
string Alias {get; set; }
string Comment { get; set; }
```

In order to style my TreeView with respect to the type of item (its class), I have also created corresponding hierarchical DataTemplates. Everything works as expected: I am able to present the contents of Alias within a TextBox in bold for ClassA and Italic in ClassB, and the contents of Comment in Tooltips for both classes.

My question is the following: Is it possible to add some sort of EventTriggers in the HierarchicalDataTemplates such that I can use a different TextBox that is bound to comment, such that my entire TreeView will display all Comments instead of Aliases whenever a certain Key is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something "quick and ugly". 
In your data template add a TextBox bound to your comment.
Then, bind the visibility of this TextBox to a boolean in your ViewModel.

Finally, when your key is pressed, trigger a command in your VM, command that will update the boolean value, therefore update the UI for the Visibility binding.

It's not very fancy, but it should work :)